# Select data in range 5 month from different year in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have data in my MySQL table that is looks like below.

```
ID  date_in   
---------------
1   2014-10-01  
2   2014-11-01  
3   2014-12-01  
4   2015-01-01  
5   2015-02-01  
6   2015-03-01  
7   2015-04-01  
8   2015-05-01  
9   2015-06-01
```

I want to select last 5 month data before this month.

Assume today is march. so the data that I select should be look like below.

```
ID  date_in   
---------------
1   2014-10-01  
2   2014-11-01  
3   2014-12-01  
4   2015-01-01  
5   2015-02-01
```

Anybody know how to do that in MySQL?

Thank you.

Comment: Basic research is alight, even encouraged, on SO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this. Replace the first argument in `date_sub` with the month needed.

```
select * from t
where dt between date_sub('2015-03-01',interval 5 month) and
date_sub('2015-03-01',interval 1 month)
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/09e64/4

Comment: thank for your answer, it works :)

Answer (score 0):

You would do:

```
select t.*
from table t
where t.date_in >= date_sub(date_sub(curdate(), interval day(curdate()) - 1 day), 
                            interval 5 month) and
      t.date_in < date_sub(curdate(), interval day(curdate()) - 1 day)
```

The expression `date_sub(curdate(), interval day(curdate()) - 1)` gets the first day of the month.